# Filtering ListView using the EditText inside the ActionBar

Tags: android, search, filter, android-actionbar, searchview

I want to carry out functionality the same as in the link below:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

However this example uses a normal EditText and I don't want to waste screen real estate. Therefore I'd prefer to use the EditText positioned inside the ActionBar, the same that is used for normal searching. How can I access this EditText in order to place a TextWatcher on it? What's the ID for it?

I want to add this TextWatcher:

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // When user changed the Text
    MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
        int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
}
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just add an `ActionView` to `ActionBar`. Then, you can access it by retrieving reference to menu item, which holds you action view and call `menuItem.getActionView()`. More in Android docs

Comment: I've got the ActionView there so that when you click the Search button, it opens up the EditText. I'm just not sure what the findViewById is in order to reference it to add a TextWatcher.

Comment: As I said, you don't need it's id. Just use `getActionView()` method of `MenuItem`

Comment: Any chance you can show me an example please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use search from menu item. Go to code below
Use this

```
EditText search;
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
RelativeLayout rl =(RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_text, null);
search=(EditText)rl.getChildAt(0);
search.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
menu.add(0, 1, 1, R.string.inlineSearch).setIcon(R.drawable.action_search).setActionView(rl).setShowAsA    ction(MenuItem.S HOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        Log.e("TextWatcher","after");
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        Log.e("TextWatcher","before");
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        Log.e("TextWatcher","onText");
    }

 };
```

and layout for search is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="horizontal" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
      >
<EditText 
android:id="@+id/search_text"
          style="@style/EditTextHoloDark"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
          android:imeActionId="1337"
          android:imeOptions="actionDone"
          android:inputType="textCapCharacters|textNoSuggestions"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:hint="Search"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:drawableLeft="@drawable/action_search"

          />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Let me know is it helpful or not.?

Comment: Same comment to the comment on my question really. How do I implement a TextWatcher on that?

Comment: Is it compulsory I define a new layout? Can't I access the Android one they've clearly already defined?

Comment: I think you can use Android one

Comment: Let me know if get problem